# creating glissando/portamento with piano roll editors

Tags: software, glissando

I'm not sure if sequence/software questions is allowed in the site, but i didn't see any explicit mention against in the faq.

I've been using several Midi sequencers with piano roll editors (Ableton, Reaper) and none of them seem to have a straightforward way to join two or more note events into a single glissando or portamento.

What is the recommended way to create continous note events in these applications? at the moment i'm using Reaper, but i am not attached to any specific application yet

Comment: This is somewhat of an edge case, in terms of on-topic-ness.  It's not really the focus of the site (i.e. practice or performance), but I would err on the side of inclusiveness for these cases.

Answer (score 2):

FL studio's piano roll would let you create a portamento by using a "slide" note.  It's been years since I've used the program, but I can't imagine that feature being taken out.